# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar datos en tablas relacionadas?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer un pequeño crud de posts y categorias *(múltiples)* en php-PDO similar al de wordpress, y necesito un ejemplo hecho:

---

Tabla students

```
---------------------------------------------
- student_id - student_name - student_image -
---------------------------------------------
-          1 - Ana          - avatar.jpg    -
-          2 - David        - avatar.jpg    -
-          3 - Jasmine      - avatar.jpg    -
---------------------------------------------
```

Tabla Courses

```
-------------------------------------------
- course_id - course_title - course_image -
-------------------------------------------
-         7 - Photoshop    - image.jpg    -
-         8 - Cinema 4D    - image.jpg    -
-         9 - Idesign      - image.jpg    -
-        10 - Illustrator  - image.jpg    -
-------------------------------------------
```

Tabla students_courses

```
--------------------------
- course_id - student_id - 
--------------------------
-         7 - 1   
-         8 - 2   
-         7 - 3     
-         9 - 2
-         9 - 3
-         8 - 1 
--------------------------
```

Este es el código del formulario:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="student_name" placeholder="Name Student" Value="David" required><br/>
<select class="form-control" name="course_id[]" multiple required>
<option value="1" selected>Photoshop</option>
<option value="2">DreamWeaver</option>
<option value="3" selected>Idesign</option>
<option value="4">Illustrator</option>
</select><br/> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </form>
```

¿Cual seria la sentencia para hacer el update?

La url en mi caso sería:

> 127.0.0.1/php/update.php?edit_id=2

Comment: Hola de nuevo, Karim. Cuál update quieres hacer? tienes que especificar qué actualización/modificación quieres hacer. ¿Quieres lograr que se pueda modificar los cursos en los que el alumno está inscrito?

Comment: Hola amigo, si lo que quiero es actualizar la ficha del alumno añadiendo,quitando cursos en el que está inscrito.

Comment: El problema, como te he venido diciendo es la manera en la que están estructuradas tus tablas. Si te fijas la tabla donde guardas cursos-alumnos solo tiene esa información, esa tabla te ayuda fácilmente a saber en qué cursos está inscrito tu alumno, pero nada más, por la estructura no puedes modificar nada porque no hay manera en que tú hagas referencia a ciertos registros, además que es posible que se repitan.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un status en la tabla de cursos_estudiantes. Y dependiendo de ese curso lo das de baja o no en la modificación. Para la baja funcionaría así: (tienes que especificar que es baja en la acción del botón y crear un método especial para la baja)
Funcionaría así: Eliges un estudiante - > Eliges un curso - > Mandas al servidor y haces una consulta con esos dos datos y verificas que el status está activo- > Si existe entonces lo das de baja (cambias el status a baja), sino pues devuelves un error.

Comment: @KarimXpert, no es necesario que crees una nueva pregunta, siempre tienes la opción de **[editar]**. En todo caso, veo que tu nueva pregunta tienes respuestas, por lo que es posible que [tu primera pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56139/78) sea eliminada.

Comment: Para alta es lo mismo, haces un select WHERE idCurso = $idCurso AND idAlumno = $idAlumno. Si no te regresa registros significa que tienes que dar de alta un nuevo registro porque ese alumno no estaba registrado anteriormente en ese curso. El status que tendrá será ALTA evidentemente.

Comment: Entonces en la tabla alumno_cursos tengo que añadir un id para hacer el where ?

Comment: Si, por que si no, vas a estar actualizando siempre los mismos registros.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob entonces tu propuesta no me va a funcionar no !?

Comment: Si te puede servir, pero no hará lo que realmente quieres, traté de acoplarla a lo que tienes, pero sería más eficiente si haces más consistente la tabla de student_courses

Comment: Ok, ya he añadido en la tabla student_courses otra columna student_courses_id, asi esta bien?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob te importaria que comparta contigo los ficheros atraves de mediafire?

Comment: alguien me puede echar una mano por favor ?

Answer (score 1):

Esta un poco raro lo que quieres hacer pero esta es mi propuesta:

Es formulario quedaría así, modifiqué tu INPUT por un SELECT, se te hará más fácil.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="php/update.php">
  <select name="student_name">
    <option value="1">Ana</option>
    <option value="2">David</option>
    <option value="3">Jasmine</option>
</select>

  <select class="form-control" name="course_id[]" multiple required>
    <option value="1" selected>Photoshop</option>
    <option value="2">DreamWeaver</option>
    <option value="3" selected>Idesign</option>
    <option value="4">Illustrator</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Este sería el back-end obviamente cambia el username y el password

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
if(isset($_POST["student_name"])){$student_name = $_POST["student_name"];}else{$student_name = "";}
if(isset($_POST["course_id"])){$course_id = $_POST["course_id"];}else{$course_id = "";}

try 
{
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=DB", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  for ($i=0; $i < count($course_id); $i++) 
  { 
      $sql = "UPDATE STUDENT_COURSES SET STUDENT_ID = $student_name WHERE COURSE_ID = ".$course_id[$i];
      $conn->exec($sql);
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Conexión fallida: " . $e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

¿Qué pasó? El valor del SELECT de los student_name va ligado al ID de la base de datos. Esto para que no tengas que poner el nombre, ir a compararlo con la base y traer el ID para hacer lo mismo.

En el PHP el valor de course_id ya viene como un arreglo, lo único que hice fue recorrerlo y hacer una sentencia por cada vez que es barrido el ciclo.

El problema aquí será que no nos has dicho en base a que se hará el UPDATE, si en base al course_id o al student_id. Yo lo hice en base al course_id.

Tu propuesta es confusa pero espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Lo que él necesito es ayuda con el update, no con el insert.

Comment: Hola Alberto, en el pdo como sería ?

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta, hechale un ojo. También hay un problema, no nos has dicho en base a que se debe hacer el UPDATE

Comment: **Atención**: Enviar esta sentencia: `$sql = "UPDATE STUDENT_COURSES SET STUDENT_ID = $student_name WHERE COURSE_ID = ".$course_id[$i];` corre el peligro de **Inyección SQL**. Imagínate que, en el formulario, donde debe de ir `$course_id`un usuario mal intencionado ponga: `1; DELETE FROM cualquiertabla` puedes así de fácil tener inyectado un código malicioso que es enviado a la BD... de esa manera podrían borrar todas las tablas de la BD y cosas peores. Por eso se recomienda usar siempre consultas preparadas, separando la parte SQL (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE...) de los datos que se envían.